# Minimum number of stickers required for 3x3 Rubik's Cube

Tags: combinatorics, rubiks-cube

Lately, the stickers on my V-Cube have been peeling off, and I became curious: what is the minimum number of stickers I would actually need in order to represent each unique configuration?

I have but a very basic knowledge of the cube laws, and so far I've reasoned that:

1) One can remove a maximum of 4 central stickers, and

2) One can remove at least 9 edge stickers (one sticker for each color to make 6 single-color edge pieces, each group of edgepieces sharing one color containing exactly two single-color edgepieces, and 3 stickers to make three completely colorless edgepieces, as each turn swaps two pairs of edges).

That is about all I can say confidently, and I have no idea how to approach the corner pieces. Any ideas?

Comment: Three completely colorless edges won't work -- you wouldn't be able to see which was which (and there are combinations that permute three edges cyclically), nor would you be able to see if you had flipped two of the edges.